# How to set up alertmanager.service for running in docker container

Tags: docker, prometheus

I am running prometheus in a docker container, and I want to configure an AlertManager for making it send me an email when the service is down. I created the  `alert_rules.yml` and the `prometheus.yml`, and I run everything with the following command, mounting both the yml files onto the docker container at the path `/etc/prometheus`:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v "$PWD/prometheus.yml":/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v "$PWD/alert_rules.yml":/etc/prometheus/alert_rules.yml prom/prometheus
```

Now, I also want prometheus to send me an email when an alert comes up, and that's where I encounter some problems. I configured my `alertmanager.yml` as follows:

```
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: email-me
receivers:
- name: 'gmail'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'my_email@gmail.com'
    from: 'askonlinetraining@gmail.com'
    smarthost: smtp.gmail.com:587
    auth_username: 'my_email@gmail.com'
    auth_identity: 'my_email@gmail.com'
    auth_password: 'the_password'
```

I actually don't know if the **smarthost** parameter is configured correctly since I can't find any documentation about it and I don't know which values it should contain
I also created an `alertmanager.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=AlertManager Server Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/alertmanager \
    --config.file /etc/alertmanager.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I think something here is messed up: I think the first parameter I pass to ExecStart is a path that doesn't exist in the container, but I have no idea on how I should replace it.
I tried mounting the last two files into the docker container in the same directory where I mount the first two yml files by using the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v "$PWD/prometheus.yml":/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v "$PWD/alert_rules.yml":/etc/prometheus/alert_rules.yml -v "$PWD/alertmanager.yml":/etc/prometheus/alertmanager.yml -v "$PWD/alertmanager.service":/etc/prometheus/alertmanager.service prom/prometheus
```

But the mailing alert is not working and I don't know how to fix the configuration for smoothly running all of this into a docker container. As I said, I suppose the main problem resides in the `ExecStart` command present in `alertmanager.service`, but maybe I'm wrong. I can't find anything helpful online, hence I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice with containers is to aim to run a single process per container.

In your container, this suggests one container for `prom/prometheus` and another for `prom/alertmanager`.

You can run these using `docker` as:

```sh
docker run \
--detach \
--name=prometheus \
--volume=${PWD}:/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
--volume=${PWD}:/rules.yml:/etc/alertmanager/rules.yml \
--publish=9090:9090 \
prom/prometheus:v2.26.0 \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/promtheus.yml

docker run \
--detach \
--name=alertmanager \
--volume=${PWD}:/rules.yml:/etc/alertmanager/rules.yml \
--publish=9093:9093 \
prom/alertmanager:v0.21.0
```

A good tool when you run multiple container is [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) in which case, your `docker-compose.yml` could be:

```
version: "3"

services:
  prometheus:
    restart: always
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.26.0
    container_name: prometheus
    command:
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - ${PWD}/rules.yml:/etc/alertmanager/rules.yml
    expose:
      - "9090"
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  alertmanager:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    image: prom/alertmanager:v0.21.0
    container_name: alertmanager
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/alertmanager.yml:/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
    expose:
      - "9093"
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
```

and you could:

```sh
docker-compose up
```

In either case, you can then browse:

- Prometheus on the host's port 9090 i.e. `localhost:9090`
- Alert Manager on the host's port 9093, i.e. `localhost:9093`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one questin though: whyare you mounting the ```rules.yml``` file both onto the prometheus container and the alertmanager container?

Comment: I managed to make it work thanks to your tips. Thank you so much!